# Windows.Forms control like "properties" table in VS

Tags: visual-studio, controls

I need a table control where one can edit properties by various ways, just like editing properties in Visual Studio (it's for XML editing). Does anybody know about something like that, written by others, or maybe a solution from MS itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx) control.